# windows crosscompiling from linux entry point not found curl_easy_cleanup could not located

Tags: c, curl

I am unsure of what could be causing this as I have tried recompiling libcurl and using pre-compiled binaries.

My compiler command

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wall -Lwin-lib -Iwin-lib -I./ -D WIN32 -D CURL_STATICLIB -mwindows ... -o win-export/SLM.exe -lm -lraylib -ltmx -lxml2 -lzlibstatic -lcurl
```

There aren't any compiler errors or linker errors. Is this a problem with my compiler? Or one the other libraries I am using?

[image: A screenshot of the error message]

Comment: Is libcurl.dll on the PATH? Or in the same directory?

Comment: is this on the windows machine or in the compiler path?